# CSS framework that works like Android layouts?

Tags: android, css, web, responsive-design

Is there any CSS framework that functions like how Android layouts work--more specifically linear layouts? I know this question is short, but I did do my homework and searched on Google and Github. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong keyword. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean a responsive CSS framework like Bootstrap that supports [stacked grid items](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)?

Comment: try Flexbox..it also uses features similar to android-weights and you can also assign the flow of the layout ( like vertical or horizontal )

Comment: I don't know why people downvote this but I really think this is a legit question--It's a question about programming, and it's something that's hard to find on Google unless you know the exact keyword. I now know the right keyword is flexbox, but I wasn't even thinking of it before, and I'm not even a programming newbie. I think it's a bully behavior to downvote something like this. Lastly I really appreciate exactly the answer I was looking for below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try http://bulma.io/ "A modern CSS framework based on Flexbox"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really don't understand why people downvote this question. I wish this doesn't get closed so people who don't know what keyword to search can land here in the future.